Send request with OAuth token in header SOAP WSDL
I am trying to send a request to a SOAP Service with OAuth authentication. The SOAP Service is on an external system outside Salesforce and i want to send the request from Salesforce. I have the WSDL and all the classes generated by it. Now i am using username and password authentication with named credentials.
This is an example of one service.

I think i can get the token through an REST request as is usually done but how can i include the result token on the request of the SOAP Service? Maybe i can change and define OAuth authentication in the Navision_Opp named credential?
Or maybe i can use this header variable in the WSDL class?

Thanks.
